# CreateProcessAsUser() not showing CreateWindow of running Process [C#]

Tags: c#

My system has 2 accounts (USER and ADMIN) and a service (Service.exe) running under LocalSystem.
The user logs into the USER account, the LocalService can then launch a process (CreateProcessAsUser(...)) as the ADMIN user.

The process the Service runs (Tool.exe) is a legacy C++ application that performs a job and also displays information to the user by using CreateWindow(...), but when launching it by the Service the Window does not show...

When the process is created by the Service I first load the Profile & Environment of the ADMIN user so that the correct context is used ...
(was still hoping the Window would display to USER)

Now, initialy I thought this would cause a problem as ADMIN is running the process so why would the CreateWindow(...) output in the USER desktop, so I tried with a simple command-line test.exe app and when launched as ADMIN the Command Prompt window appeared - so why does that work fine where-as the CreateWindow(...) doesn't display correctly?

Any clues on how I can get the STATUS (using CreateWindow in Tool.exe) running under ADMIN to show in the USER logged-on session?

Can I use the ENVIRONMENT somehow, I tried the following thinking it might work but didn't:

```
startInfo.lpDesktop = @"WinSta0\Default";
startInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
startInfo.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW;
```

The Window is created as follows (in Tool.exe):

```
HWND hwnd = CreateWindow
(
    "Tool", 
    "Tool WINDOW",
    WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE,
    0,0,uWidth,uHeight,
    NULL, 
    NULL, 
    hInstance, 
    Text
);
```

Is the lpDesktop wrong (not exactly sure how this works)?

I know how crazy this sounds - I just would rather not have to launch another ToolDisplay.exe as USER which communicates with Tool.exe as ADMIN as a display when the Tool.exe used to handle everything on its own - so checking to see if there isn't some nice way to handle this...

Any help would be much appreciated...
Thanks,

[Simplified Question:]

My system has 2 accounts (USER and ADMIN), the user is always logged on as USER but at some specific times a process (Tool.exe) is launched under the ADMIN account (by a LocalSystem Service using CreateProcessAsUser(...)), almost everything works fine except for the fact that the process (Tool.exe) is supposed to display status to the user using CreateWindow(...).

When Tool.exe is running (as ADMIN) and the user is logged-on as USER the window is not shown (obviously)...
Is there a way to show the window of Tool.exe running under ADMIN to the user logged-on as USER?

Any help would be much appreciated...
Thanks,

Comment: Simplify your question. It is not making any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want a window / GUI spawned by a service to be visible,
 Go to-> run prompt -> services.msc -> go to your service's property, check "Allow service to interact with desktop".
Then restart your service.

Note that in Vista, the prompt will NOT be visible even after above. This is due to sessions issue. However there is a service which helps support prompts from services (I think it is Interactive Services Detection service).

Comment: Right.  Beware of potential security risks as this may allow the LSA account to be "hi-jacked".  Maybe you can run the service under a "normal" account.

Comment: Service must be run under ADMIN account as it performs admin actions. And only USER is ever logged-on.

The service isn't the one doing the CreateWindow, the Tool.exe run in ADMIN is ... so "Allow service to interact with desktop" doesn't help (already done)...

Comment: Why do want to runas tool.exe as Admin? If you just require administrative privileges, services have more rights that admin users.So directly spawn the tool.exe using the service (Don't do runas Admin).
Also try spawning the test app via the service & see if it works.